# How can I ignore unrecognized properties using javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation.Builder?

Tags: java, web-services, jackson, invocation

I have built a web client which uses SSL.

The client is initialized like this:

```
SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("ssl");
        sc.init(null, noopTrustManager, null);
        
        this.client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().
                sslContext(sc).
                build();
```

Then the web target is initialized like this:

```
this.webTarget = this.client.target(urlAddress);
```

And the Invocation Builder is initialized like this:

```
Builder request = this.webTarget.request();
```

But when - after setting the headers appropriately - I try to do this:

```
request.get(InitiateTransferResponse.class);
```

I get the following error message:

> javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "timestamp" (class com.interaxa.ivr.visual.moa.service.model.InitiateTransferResponse), not marked as ignorable

Is there a way to tell the builder to ignore all unrecognized properties? (I intend to use this same builder for other web services too, and it would be nice if I could set it to ignore unknown properties permanently, regardless of the response class).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution!

The key is to replace the line:
`request.get(InitiateTransferResponse.class);`

By this code:

```
        InitiateTransferResponse result;
        try {
            result = getMapper().readValue(response, InitiateTransferResponse.class);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            ViewFactory.logError(e);
            result = null;
        }
```

Where `getMapper()` is as follows:

```
public ObjectMapper getMapper() {
        if (mapper == null){
            mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
            mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES, false);
            mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Inclusion.NON_NULL);
        }
        return mapper;
}
```

And ObjectMapper is `org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper`.

This way, the ObjectMapper controls what it lets through rather than leaving that decision to the Builder.